# Changing output after delay in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get an app which updates it output after a set amount of time (i.e. to make text fade away).

In the example code, I would want "Waiting" to display on the actionButton press, then delay for 5 seconds, then the text changes to "Finished".

For some reason the whole observeEvent executes at once, so the outcome is that there is the actionButton is pressed, then there is a 5 second delay with nothing displayed, then "Finished" displays.

Sorry I don't know how to better explain the issue really - but hoping someone can help. If possible I'd like to stick to just R here, without delving too much into javascript.

````
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textOutput("text"),
  actionButton("press", label = "press")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  num <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$press, {
    output$text <- renderText("waiting")
    num(1)
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(num())){
      output$text <- renderText({
        Sys.sleep(5)
        "finished"
        })
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Comment: Does it need to be updating text or could you use a popup like interaction? If the latter, I commonly use shinyModal while things are being calculated on the backend.

Comment: I'll look into shinyModal - the trigger could be dismissing of a popup window possibly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **delay()** function from **shinyjs**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textOutput("text"),
  actionButton("press", label = "press")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  num <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$press, {
  output$text <- renderText("waiting")
  delay(5000,
      output$text <- renderText("finished"))
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you - I don't know how I didn't manage to get this solution earlier.

Comment: I am glad it helped. There are many **javascript"** functionalities coming to R through libraries such as shinyjs. More recently I saw that now shiny is handling *promises* and *callback functions*